# Unable to load CSS of Static files

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I've just created a Django app. When I am running the server content is displaying but CSS styles are not applying.

Here is my settings configuration of staticfiles.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
      os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
      ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

urls configuration of staticfiles.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

here is code of html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>MyApp</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache of your browser or use an extension called Cache cleaner. It should load the files then.

Comment: i have cleared the cache. but again showing the same problem.

Comment: What's the name of the folder where you're storing all your static files

Comment: @ Fanceh, Thanks for your helping.now it's working fine . the error occurred in folder structure as you mentioned in above comment.

Comment: No problem! It would be appreciated if you could upvote and mark my comment as answer (: